# How to configure spark runner for apache beam pipeline for java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-beam

I'm new to Apache Beam and Apace spark, i want to configure the beam pipeline for spark runner. what is mentioned in the documentation is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass argument `--runner SparkRunner` to the pipeline launcher to use spark as the underlying runner. Also, Please share what language of Beam SDK you are using. Python and java have some what different ways to run on Spark via Beam.

Comment: thank you for the reply. i'm using java with beam version 2.18.0. furthermore i want to know how this runner expose features / functions of Spark which can be used in my application. Guide to how to use them would also be much helpful

Comment: Thanks for the info. For java, you can use "Non Portable" spark runner. which is the easiest to use at the moment. Please follow the instructions here https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/ We can debug specific error that you might get by following the process in the document.

Comment: @Ankur How should one try apache beam with Python using Spark runner. I tried installing pyspark package from pypi but doesnt seem to work

Comment: You will need portable runner implementation of beam to run py on spark. More details here https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/#which-runner-to-use-portable-or-non-portable-runner